# Usage of HOSTNAME and CURRENT_USER in scripts on linux

Tags: linux, unix, environment-variables

Suppose I want to edit `/etc/profile`:

`PYTHONPATH = /home/CURRENT_USER/`

1. How do I have a **variable** that will automatically fill in the
   current user?
2. What about **hostname**?
3. Aren't these environment variables?

Comment: One thing to be careful with here - if you ever run this script as root by using `sudo`, then both `whoami` and `$USER` will return `root`, regardless of what user ran the script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$USER` should typically be set to the current user, and `$HOSTNAME` to the current hostname. If not, you can also get them from the output of `whoami` and `hostname`

Also, the user's home directory is not necessarily in `/home/[username]`. You should use the value of `$HOME` instead.

Comment: Why is it that when I type $HOSTNAME in my terminal command, it says: bash: /root: is a directory

Comment: No, you need to `echo $HOSTNAME`. If you just give bash a variable as a command, how is it supposed to know what action to take on it?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to see all of your environmental variables available, use the following command:

```
bash$ set
```

Remember case sensitivity, for hostname you'll need $HOSTNAME, and $USER

```
bash$ echo $USER
sparks
bash$ echo $HOSTNAME
servername
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to add a call to `sys.addsitedir` in `sitecustomize.py` rather than PYTHONPATH.

However since Python 2.6 you probably don't need to do either, because `/home/$USER/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages` is automatically added to `sys.path`. This is a good choice of standard place to put user-specific modules/packages; you wouldn't really want to add the home directory itself as a module path as it contains all sorts of things that aren't modules, which could confuse imports.

See [PEP370](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

In python, call os.uname() to get the hostname (and other details in an array).